# How to use LibreOffice Calc 'set' datatype

Tags: set, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet like this: a1=3, b1=(1..10,15)
How do I check if a1 is in b1?
```=if (a1 in b1, 'tada!', 'Missed it')``? Is this correct?

Comment: Tell me, is the form 1..10 important for you? The point is, if you write the range as 1-10, then I will offer a solution immediately

Comment: No. Just indicating set of integers 1 to 10. (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try [**this extension**](https://sites.google.com/site/vladjohnorlov/programmy-na-vse-slucai/plaski-vokrug-ofisa/ListOK.oxt?attredirects=0&d=1). (This was written many years ago to record numbers on insurance policy forms.)

The extension contains several functions, the name of each of which begins with LST, in the Function Wizard they are located in the Add-In section.

[image: Add-In section in the Function Wizard]

The lists of numbers that are passed to the function must be sets of positive integers. Numbers separated by - + = or _ signify an interval of values, other non-digit characters (including period, comma, space) are regarded as separators of separate numbers. Therefore `1..10,15` from your example will be converted to `1, 10, 15`, use the sign -

A few examples will help you understand the purpose of the individual functions. The last line is the answer to your question.

[image: ListOK examples]

**Updated.** From Basic all this functions calling like as embedded Calc functions, with service FunctionAccess

```
Function IsOnPeak(C2 As Variant, I13 As String, D2  As Variant, I16 As String) As Boolean 
Dim Mth As Integer 
Dim hr As Integer  
Dim svFA As Variant
    Mth =Month(C2)    
    hr = HOUR(D2) 
    svFA = createUnoService( "com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess" )
    IsOnPeak = (svFA.callFunction("LSTOR",Array(Mth,I13)) <> "") And (svFA.callFunction("LSTOR",Array(Hr, I16)) <> "")
End Function
```

Comment: OK. This works in Calc. I need to use it in a Libre Basic macro. I get the not defined message. This is my script ```FUNCTION IsOnPeak(C2,I13,D2,I16)
  DIM HourIN as boolean
  DIM MonthIn as boolean
  DIM Mth as Integer
  DIM hr as integer

  Mth =Month(C2) 
  hr = HOUR(D2)
  MonthIn =LSTOR(Mth,I13)
  HourIn = LSTOR(Hr, I16)
  if MonthIn and HourIn then
     IsOnPeak =TRUE
  else  
    IsOnPeak = FALSE 
  endif    
End FUNCTION``` Can you show me how to use LSTOR in the script?

Comment: Why not simple `=AND(LSTOR(MONTH(C2);$I$13)<>"";LSTOR(HOUR(D2);I16)<>"")`?

Comment: That's it! Perfecto! Thanks...Dan'l