# Get a conditional result

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Adding detail.
I have a spreadsheet like this:

````
B           C       D       E       F   G           H   
Date        Time    Kwh $/KwCost        Hours/MonthsCost/Kwh
2021-01-01  0:15    0.69    $0.00   0   months      $0.15
2021-01-01  0:30    0.51    $0.00   0   11-12,1-5   $0.05
01/08/21    0:45    0.3     $0.00   0   hours   
2021-01-01  1:00    0.76    $0.00   0   06-08,15-20 ```
````

The rules: if the month # is in g3 and the hour# is in g5 then $h$2.

I am using

`=iF (LSTOR(MONTH(c2),$h$3)= MONTH(c2)) and (LSTOR(HOUR(d2),$h$5)=HOUR(d2)) then $i$2 else $i$3`

but I am getting

> 509   Missing operator    Operator is missing, for example, "=2(3+4) * ",
> where the operator between "2" and "(" is missing.)

Can someone show me where the error is?

Comment: Excuse me, If the letters of the columns in your example are correct, then this formula will never work. Let's take a look together. You are trying to take MONTH(C2), but the dates are not in column C, they are in column B; you are trying to take HOUR(D2), but there is no time in column D, etc. In your example, the values in cells I2 and I3 are not visible. In Calc, "and" is not an operator, it is a separate function AND()

Comment: I'm not sure iabout the syntax `if ... then ... else....` is working in LO Calc. The [documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Logical_Functions#IF) has `IF(Test; ThenValue; OtherwiseValue)`. BTW: whats's "LSTOR"?

Comment: @tohuwawohu LSTOR() is function from add-in (see this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66295342/14094617)). By the way, you really hit a sore spot! All functions in this version of the add-in work with the positive integers (excluding zero). And the author of the question tries to use HOUR(0:45) = 0 as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that all functions in this version of the [**ListOK**](https://sites.google.com/site/vladjohnorlov/programmy-na-vse-slucai/plaski-vokrug-ofisa/ListOK.oxt?attredirects=0&d=1) add-in work with positive integers (except zero), you must specify values in the G5 shift ranges, `7-9,16-21` instead of `06-08,15-20`. In this case, the formula

```
=IF(OR(LSTOR(MONTH(B2);$G$3)="";LSTOR(HOUR(C2)+1;$G$5)="");$J$3;$J$2)
```

should give you the desired result.

Comment: Adjusting for the cell references, this works ```=IF(OR(LSTOR(MONTH(B4),$H$3)="",LSTOR(HOUR(D4)+1,$H$5)=""),$I$3,$I$2)```.  Thanks JohnSUN